# How to hand over bash variable to your python script?

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

I am rather new to bash scripting, more used to batch. Anyways what I am trying to do is to be able to get a string from a bash variable that is created from an nmap scan and make it a variable for a python script. I was going to use grep but it gets too much. Here are the results:

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-05-22 20:12 PDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.201
Host is up (0.00020s latency).
Not shown: 96 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
135/tcp  open  msrpc
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
3389/tcp open  ms-term-serv
MAC Address: 02:21:9B:88:3C:06 (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.77 seconds
```

What I want to get is: `MAC Address: 02:21:9B:88:3C:06` WITH the space at the end. SO it would be `MAC=$`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
MAC=$(egrep -o '^MAC Address: (..:){5}.. ' filename.txt)
```

The `-o` option makes `egrep` just output the part of the line that matches the regexp, so it will just go up to the space after the address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` and pipe (`|`) to `awk` :

```
MAC=`grep -a 'MAC' Nmapscan.txt | awk -F ' ' {'print $1" "$2" "$3" " '}`
```

Or

```
MAC=`nmap 192.168.1.201 | grep 'MAC' | awk -F ' ' {'print $1" "$2" "$3" " '}`
```

If possible I'd strongly recommend adding this change too for security:

```
NMAP_FILE=`mktemp`

# start
nmap 192.168.1.201 > $NMAP_FILE

# middle
MAC=`grep -a 'MAC' $NMAP_FILE | awk -F ' ' {'print $1" "$2" "$3" " '}`

# end
rm -f $NMAP_FILE
```

To pass the `$MAC` over to your python script you can use:

```
ALERT.py $MAC &
```

and add this to `ALERT.py`

```
import sys

mac_address = sys.argv[0]

# now `mac_address` is "MAC Address: 02:21:... "
```

Comment: I use the file that it output for a few things in the script. If I use grep -a "MAC" Nmapscan.txt to get MAC Address: 02:21:9B:88:3C:06 (Unknown), how can I get just the MAC Address: 02:21:9B:88:3C:06 ? Without using the pipe and nmap? Thank you

Comment: @user3525621 You can drop the ````nmap```` and the first ````|```` if you already have the output in a file. Edited answer shows how.

Comment: @user3525621 I will also add that writing the ````nmap```` output to a file would not be secure as there is a chance that it could be edited after writing and before reading. Safer to just store it in a variable or if you insist on writing a file you can investigate the ````mktemp```` command which allows you to make a temporary  (randomly named) file which you can delete at the end of your script.

Comment: I would rather store it as a variable, but I need to use a python scrip to be able to read the variable, that is why I thought of using a txt file to store it, unless you have a better idea?

Comment: @user3525621 do you call the python script from the bash script?

Comment: Yes, well want to make a python script run while the rest of the code runs, but yes, the same bash is going to launch the python script.

Comment: If you run the python script from the above script you can pass in the temporary file's path as an argument i.e: ````your-python-script.py $NMAP_FILE &```` and read it from the python script with ````nmap_file = sys.argv[0]```` Note: you must ````import sys````

Comment: WOW!! Never knew that, thank you. I do not have my whole script, it is on a different machine, but I will def try that line of code tomorrow and get back to you.  So what would the code be if the python script was called ALERT.py and the nmap scan resuls file is called NmapScanResults.txt? And do I have include code in the bash file as well as the python script? Sorry, crunch time on my senior project, and never used Linux till now.

Comment: @user3525621 to clarify: ````ALERT.py $NMAP_FILE &```` is bash code to call your python script in the background with ````$NMAP_FILE```` (the randomly named temporary file we used) as an argument. ````nmap_file = sys.argv[0]```` is python code which goes in ````ALERT.py```` which will read the argument you passed in from bash and save it in the variable ````nmap_file````. If you edit your question to mention handing over to your python script I'll put this in my answer with proper formatting :)

Comment: I changed the question to relate to the new topic as well as answer